# How do I enable blood/gore?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

I'm watching clips of people using katanas chopping enemies up to bits, but when I'm using katanas, even doing the finisher that slices the head, nothing happens besides the body just flying through the air. No gore except for shotgun dismemberment. I'm trying to locate a setting that enables gore or even figure out how to turn on gore but can't seem to find anything in the settings menu, either in the menu or in-game. Any help?

Comment: Could it be mods maybe? Nexus Mods seems to have this popular one https://www.nexusmods.com/cyberpunk2077/mods/3040 (you need an account and need to have adult content enabled for your profile to view it)

Comment: A lot of reddit comments say gore should be enabled by default in the base game (except for German versions), and I have no mods on my system.

Comment: This is weird. I use a german version via steam and while excessively using grenades and tech weapons I had pretty much to clean up.

Can you clarify if you're talking about civilians or actual enemies like Tyger Claws? 
On civilians you will not see gore. On enemies you should. 

Most of the reddit threads are outdated as they refer to older patches. There might have been changes in the meantime. I will check ingame if there's a setting for that.

Comment: Are you using a mod in your weapon or Kiroshi implant that makes all your attacks non-lethal?